# how to transform a cst file in visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, authorize.net

Authorize.NET offers a template file called [ControllerTemplate.cst](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-dotnet/blob/master/Authorize.NET/Api/ControllerTemplate.cst):

```
namespace AuthorizeNet.Api.Controllers
{
    using System;
    using AuthorizeNet.Api.Contracts.V1;
    using AuthorizeNet.Api.Controllers.Bases;

#pragma warning disable 1591
    public class APICONTROLLERNAMEController : ApiOperationBase<APICONTROLLERNAMERequest, APICONTROLLERNAMEResponse> {

        public APICONTROLLERNAMEController(APICONTROLLERNAMERequest apiRequest) : base(apiRequest) {
        }

        override protected void ValidateRequest() {
            var request = GetApiRequest();

            //validate required fields      
            //if ( 0 == request.SearchType) throw new ArgumentException( "SearchType cannot be null");
            //if ( null == request.Paging) throw new ArgumentException("Paging cannot be null");

            //validate not-required fields      
        }

        protected override void BeforeExecute()
        {
            var request = GetApiRequest();
            RequestFactoryWithSpecified.APICONTROLLERNAMEType(request);
        }
    }
#pragma warning restore 1591
}
```

Honestly, I've never used transforms, and I've been trying to transform it by right clicking on it, and [then running custom tool](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOfcI8TJT6SIHve-3Ggc2wrtQjeeB76km8a44_VF-Y6RSAk3yd_PNwfy5uDr2HgAw?key=MHZNMG1iWGd0VUNrMEZmU3Z4MVc4cjNJVTZCMVFR).

**How do I transform this template and create one of these files for every controller in the project?**

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the nustache package (available in nugget). You can render the file in using something like

in the usings :

```
 using Nustache.Core;
```

in you method :

```
 Render.FileToFile(templateFile, model, Path.Combine(outFolder, outFileName));
```